# Как при помощи концептов проверить возвращаемый из функции шаблонный тип? С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как при помощи type traits или концептов понять, что тип `std::optional<int>` и `std::optional<double>` - это инстанцирование одного и того же класса `std::optional`? Как написать функцию, которая бы принимала функцию, которая возвращает `std::optional<T>`, где T - это любой его тип? У меня загвоздка именно в том, что я не знаю как определить, что функция возвращает именно `optional`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T> struct IsStdOptional : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct IsStdOptional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

Дальше как угодно. Можно в лоб:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F &&func) requires IsStdOptional<decltype(std::forward<F>(func)())>::value {}
```

Можно так:

```
template <typename T>
concept StdOptional = IsStdOptional<T>::value;

template <typename F>
void foo(F &&func) requires requires{{std::forward<F>(func)()} -> StdOptional;} {}
```

Comment: Я со всей этой стандартной библиотекой уже забыл, что можно сделать свое)

Comment: А насколько можно это сделать универсальным? Например `common_template<T, M>`, который вычислял бы общий тип двух его инстанцирований?

Comment: @ComeInRage Про общий тип не понял. [Можно так](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/imp-re/blob/master/src/meta/common.h#L66-L79=), тогда `-> StdOptional` превращается в `-> specialization_of<std::optional>`. Но есть минус - `typename...` принимает только параметры-типы, поэтому `specialization_of<std::array>` (у которого второй параметр - не тип) не работает. Чтобы поддерживать любые шаблоны, надо городить 2^N версий со всеми комбинациями `auto` и `typename`.